# How to specify encoding in rOracle

Tags: r, oracle, encoding, roracle

I've got some troubles with R's package "rOracle" reading cyrillic data from db. I changed my nls_lang option of oracle to AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251 so that sqlQuery in rODBC package works fine with option DBMSencoding = "CP1251", but i don't know how to specify encoding to read using rOracle's dbGetQuery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set NLS_LANG environment variable before starting R

```
set NLS_LANG=BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252
```